# Delphi xe8, Cannot rename component xxx, component was introduced in an ancestor form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am going the delphi XE 8 tutoial found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_IDE_for_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder. The problem I am having is that I've followed the tutorial step by step and I keep getting an error when trying to rename the ActionList or MainMenu that says Cannot rename component xxx, component was introduced in an ancestor form.

I don't know how to fix this issue and I can also not delete the components so I have no clue what to do to fix it.

Comment: You need to rename the component in the ancestor form where it is declared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Design view locate the `Views:` dropdown. Select 'Master' and you will be able to rename the components on the form.

[image]